# Display content horizontally, but stacked when screen width does not permit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What is the best practise for displaying content side by side when the width is there such as:

[content]  [content]  [content] [content]

But when the screen size is not large enough the content automatically stacks:

[content]

[content]

[content]

I want to do this in the simplest way without having to load a framework such as bootstrap.  My content does use jQuery if that helps.

My application is a mobile HTML site that needs to also look good on larger screens such as tablets or desktop computers.  My content would be in div's.

It would be nice if it first went to:

[content] [content]

[content] [content]

Comment: I would read up on [responsive design](https://google.com/search?q=responsive+design).

Comment: The simplest approach solved my problem.  Check the demo if you have same issue.  3 lines of css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want this kind of behavior.

If yes then `float` is the css property that you should be looking for

[**Check Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/VeFjv/)

Comment: This worked perfectly and was very simple and easy to implement.

Comment: One thing, sorry, but the content aligns left .. Is there any way to make it center?

Comment: @MichaelDeMutis float property aligns the element to either left or right.

Comment: to center a grid of floating elements you have to wrap them in a container. The container can be centered using absolute positioning or auto-width margins.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use media queries to accomplish that.

Google for CSS Media Queries

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible way to accomplish this

a) Use min-width & float:left property

min-width will ensure that your div don't get smaller than specified size & float left will ensure that if there is space for div element it can go up

```
        <html>
         <head>
         <style type='text/css'>
         body{
          width:100%;
          height:100%;

         }
         body div{
          float:left;
          width:33%;
          height:200px;
          min-width:200px; 
         }
            .width1{
             background-color:red;
            }
            .width2{
             background-color:green;
            }
            .width3{
             background-color:blue;
            }
         </style>

         <body>


           <div class="width1"></div>
           <div class="width2"></div>
           <div class="width3"></div>

         </body>

         </html>
```

b) Second and more efficient way to do it is use media query

```
        <html>
         <head>
          <style type='text/css'>
         body{
          width:100%;
          height:100%;

         }
         body div{
          float:left;
          width:33%;
          height:200px;
         }
            .width1{
             background-color:red;
            }
            .width2{
             background-color:green;
            }
            .width3{
             background-color:blue;
            }

         @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { /* for 640px screen set size of div to 50%; */
          body div{
           width:50%;
          }
         }

          @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { /* for smaller screen set size of div to 100%; */
          body div{
           width:100%;
          }
         }
         </style>

         <body>


           <div class="width1"></div>
           <div class="width2"></div>
           <div class="width3"></div>

         </body>

         </html>
```

Comment: While I do not doubt that your method will work, I was looking for a simpler approach without having to use the @media css rule.

Comment: I see @sanjeev but I also want the boxes to center at the same time.. how?